# Как получить значение div по кнопке

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, у меня есть:

```
<div id="comments">
<a class="close" style="font-size:18px;">удалить</a>
<a id="showName"> Имя заголовка</a>
<p class="read-more" id="showComment"> Текс</p>
 </div>
<div id="comments">
<a class="close" style="font-size:18px;">удалить</a>
<a id="showName"> Имя заголовка2</a>
<p class="read-more" id="showComment"> Текст2</p>
 </div>
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатие на слово "удалить" - передавались данные с текста на сервер (на php) к примеру через ajax(это я уже сам)
Пробовал разными способами, как перебирать через each (
получал значение только первого)

```
$("#comments").each(function (index, all) {
  $(".close").click(function(event){
    console.log($("#showName").text());
    });
     })
```

Как через события вешать, что-то не получается.
Повторюсь, мне нужно чтобы я нажимал на удалить (.close), и как-то мог получать содержание именно значение текста (#showComment) - то как видите в колонках разные значения.
Ну в общем, чтобы к примеру как в ютубе было. Нажимаешь на крестик - и удаляется комментарий.Если есть, посоветуйте другие способы как так можно сделать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: вместо console.log($("#showName").text());   поставьте console.log($(this).parents('#comments').find("#showName").html());

Comment: Воу спасибо, ты мой спаситель :). 
То столько голову над этим ломал. Все таки в js по знаниям еще плаваю..

Answer (score 1):

несколько элементов с одинаковым id на странице не будет работать..
id должен быть уникальным.

```
    <div class="comments">
        <a class="closee" style="font-size:18px;">delete</a>
        <a class="showName"> Имя заголовка</a>
        <p class="read-more" id="showComment"> text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comments">
        <a class="closee" style="font-size:18px;">delete</a>
        <a class="showName"> Имя заголовка2</a>
        <p class="read-more" id="showComment"> text2</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.closee').click(function () {
            el = $(this).parent();
            console.log($(el).find('.showName').html());
        })

    </script>
```